# VMware – networking setup config

Tags: networking, dns, vmware

I have VMware and I have three WS2012 machines.
I made one of them into a domain. 
I want the other two to join to the domain.

I am unsure exactly of the network adapters and configuration to use/set as per this:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2016/01/14/build-clustered-msmq-role-on-a-windows-server-2012-r2-failover-cluster/

> Establish Private Network 1 (clusterNet)
>
> This will be a private network between DC, Node1 and Node2. It provides connectivity for DC/DNS communication (eg: DC - 1.2.3.1/24, Node1 - 1.2.3.2/24, Node2 1.2.3.3/24)
>
> Establish Private Network 2 (nodeNet)
>
> This will be a private network between Node1 and Node2. This network provides connectivity for sync up between the cluster nodes (eg: Node1 - 2.1.1.2/24, Node2 - 2.1.1.3/24)

Can someone kindly help me in terms of what/how many network adapters to add to each instance, what their IP, DNS and gateway should be?
They can connect to the host (I have a DHCP router/DNS that also connects to the internet) if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

Within VMware, private network means that your virtual machines can only talk to each other, but they cannot talk to anything on the outside.  You can do that if you want, but that means none of your nodes will have internet access (and thus, no access Windows Updates).

Each VM only needs one network adapter.  Even if you have DHCP, give your DC a static IP address.  DNS servers would be irrelevant if you're using private networking.

The important point comes when setting up Node1 and Node2.  For those, DHCP is OK, but you want to use the DC's IP address as the DNS server.  So, for example:

DC:

- IP address: 192.168.0.10
- Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.0.1
- DNS:  leave blank

Node1:

- IP address: 192.168.0.x (or use DHCP)
- Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.0.1
- DNS: 192.168.0.10  (same as the IP address for DC)

Node2 would follow the same pattern as Node1.  When you join the nodes to the domain, they will need to have DC as their primary DNS server.

Comment: Thanks Charles. Essentially will need multiple NIC's for failover setup etc... and what not I guess for each of the VM's, they need 3 NIC's. I'll try your suggestion to see if I can get the node's to see and join the domain

Comment: ok, failed! With the configuration stated on the website, how can I get NodeA and NodeB to see the DC?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I’m not sure why the suggestion to leave the DNS server blank on the DC. That will break the DC. Make sure the DC has a DNS server set of 127.0.0.1. It has to be able to find itself. In VMware simply create two virtual network switches and add two network interfaces to each node - one hooked to each vSwitch. The clusterNet is a public NAT network and the NodeNet is a private network. Internet access and data plane traffic is obtained through the public vSwitch while cluster syncing will happen over the private vSwitch. Gateway and DNS is configured on the public interface.

Comment: OK, so I managed to get it to work. Yay. The 2 nodes are joined to the DC. I am now trying to run the failover configuration and it passes with 2 warnings. one is that the network adapter on both nodes do not have a default gateway assigned, which is true.  What should the default gateway be on the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

- Disable DHCP in VMware
- Disable all VM's firewall
- do ping from each node
- make sure DC static ip address mentioned in dns address of other 2
  nodes.
- leave DC DNS as blank.
- now they should be able to connect domain
- do nltest /sc_query:superuser.com [your domain name] from 2 clients
  if any error kindly look in forum again.

Mostly works